# Get SharedPreferences value

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the value of my switch1 which I'm setting with:

```
switch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (switch1.isChecked()) {
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("reminder", "0");
      editor.commit();
    } else {
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("reminder", "1");
      editor.commit();
    }

  }
});
```

And to get the value:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
String silent = settings.getString("reminder", "1");
```

But what do I have to put in if? Something like...

```
if (Objects.equals(settings, "1")) {
  switch1.setChecked(true);
} else {
  switch1.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: It seems like, that ``Objects.equals(settings, "1")`` is not retrieving the value, its always 1.

Comment: Use `Objects.equals(silent, "1")`

Comment: I was absolutely sure I already tried this... Thank you, it worked.

Comment: posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use onClickListener for your Switch component, try this:

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("reminder", isChecked? "1" : "0") ;
      editor.commit();
}     
});
```

Then when compare :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
String silent = settings.getString("reminder", "1");

if (silent.equals("1")) {
  switch1.setChecked(true);
} else {
  switch1.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: You forgot ``});`` on the upper example. Thank you very much, I'm using this code now, works better. :)

Comment: oh yes, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

Replace the

```
if(Objects.equals(settings, "1")){ ... }
```

with

```
if(Objects.equals(silent, "1")){ ... }
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are doing is saving the state of a `switch` in `sharedpreferences` to read it after, why saving as `String` and not as `Boolean`? You will avoid a couple of checkes and casts.

You can easily do something like this:

**To save SharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);       
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("reminder", switch1.isChecked());
editor.apply();
```

**To read SharedPreferences:**

```
switch1.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("reminder", true));
```

Obv you can edit the code to save any type you want

Hope this helps :)

**Plus**

Also, as Diego pointed out, using `onClick` is not the best approach for switch. It's better to use the `checkedChangeListener` to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Use putBoolean/getBoolean methods instead of putString/getString